# Spring multiple @Transactional datasources

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactional

```xml
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="data.emf" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


<bean id="transactionManager2" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="data.emf" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager2" />
```

In my service layer, can I use `@Transactional(name="transactionManager2");`  to identify which transaction manager I use if I have multiple transaction managers?

Comment: Why do you think you need two transaction managers?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can specify which tx manager to use with `@Transactional` using the [`value` attribute](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#value%28%29):

> A qualifier value for the specified
>   transaction.
>
> May be used to determine the target
>   transaction manager, matching the
>   qualifier value (or the bean name) of
>   a specific PlatformTransactionManager
>   bean definition.

For example:

```
@Transactional("txManager1");
```

Alternatively, you can use the more explicit `TransactionProxyFactoryBean`, which gives you finer-grained control over what objects gets proxied by what tx managers. This still uses the annotations, but it doesn't auto-detect beans, it's configured explicitly on a bean-by-bean basis.

This normally isn't an issue, but it's not wise to have multiple transaction managers unless you have a very good reason to do so. If you find yourself needing two tx managers, it's usually better to see if you can make do with one. For example, if you have two data sources configured in your app server, you can incorporate both in a single JtaTransactionManager, rather than two seperate `JpaTransactionManager` or `DataSourceTransactionmanagers`.

Comment: please comment on my post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962509/which-sessionfactory-should-be-use-for-transactionmanager

Comment: i read from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902997/multiple-database-with-springhibernatejpa , it's using multiple org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager  and will be pointed by @transactional("name") . so this way is ok?

Comment: @skaffman, how can I associate two data sources to the same transactionmanager if I am using DataSourceTransactionManager?

Comment: @skaffman, I am working with jdbc templates and org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource, what should I do to have transactionManager for two datasources? Thanks again

Comment: @tsunade21: You open up a new question.

Comment: [Spring JTA multiple resource transactions in Tomcat with Atomikos example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/spring-jta-multiple-resource-transactions-in-tomcat-with-atomikos-example.html)

Comment: @skaffman Are you aware of any pros/cons regarding performance when using JTA instead Local JpaTransactionManager?

Comment: Note you have to use `org.springframework.transaction.annotation` in this case, not `javax.*`.

Answer (score 2):

More on the need for more than one transaction manager. You might be trying to do nested or separate transactions in sequence -- then you can use different propagation settings. You can achieve that with configuration using single transaction manager see [Transaction propagation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation).