# How to configure transaction management for working with 2 different db in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions, multiple-databases

I have 2 databases (MySql and HSQLDB). I configured 2 data sources and 2 EntityManagerFactory beans. I can also configure 2 correspondent JpaTransactionManager beans.

But I don't know how to specify which of them should be used to manage transactions for concrete service-class. I want to use `@Transactional` annotation for that purpose, but I actually can specify only one of txManagers:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="manager"/>
```

What is the way out from this situation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961371/spring-multiple-transactional-datasource

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [javadoc for JpaTransactionManager](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTransactionManager.html) has some advice on this:

> This transaction manager is
>   appropriate for applications that use
>   a single JPA EntityManagerFactory for
>   transactional data access. JTA
>   (usually through
>   JtaTransactionManager) is necessary
>   for accessing multiple transactional
>   resources within the same transaction.
>   Note that you need to configure your
>   JPA provider accordingly in order to
>   make it participate in JTA
>   transactions.

In other words, if you find yourself with multiple entity managers, with corresponding tx managers, then you should consider using a single [`JtaTransactionManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/jta/JtaTransactionManager.html) instead. The entity managers should be able to participate in JTA transactions, and this will give you full transactionality across both entity managers, without hacving to worry about which entity manager you're in at any one time.

Of course, `JtaTransactionManager` does require a full JTA-supporting application server, rather than a vanilla servlet engine like Tomcat.

Comment: I probably don't understand something, but I thought that transaction manager, used in Spring, is based on database transaction manager i.e. we should create as many tx-managers as many different databases we use. Is it wrong?

Comment: It's not quite that simple. Spring TX managers are just wrappers around other existing mechanisms such as JTA, JPA/Hibernate or JDBC transactions. JTA is not tied to one database, it's a distributed multi-database tx manager. Using Spring doesn't really change how the underlying mechanisms should be used, it just makes it easier.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds a bit unexpected to me, I'll look for it in Sun documentation.

Comment: What happens if I annotate a method with 2 @Transactional() like  :@Transactional(transactionManager = "customerTransactionManager"), @Transactional(transactionManager = "orderTransactionManager") ? I would like to know how to handle both db transactional in one method.

Answer (score 19):

Declare your `<tx:annotation-driven>` without *transaction-manager* attribute, declare qualifiers for transaction managers like this:

```
<bean id="jpaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <qualifier value="txManager1"/>
</bean>
```

Use this qualifier in *@Transactional* as a *value* to select one of transaction managers:

```
@Transactional("txManager1")
```

or, with more properties:

```
@Transactional(value = "txManager1", readOnly = true)
```

Comment: This solution works. However, if you do have a qualifier on the @Transactional annotation you must specify a transaction manager with the qualifier element configured. At first I thought that the default transaction manager would take over, but that was not the case for me. It complained that I didn't have a proper qualifier configured on my transaction manager bean.

Comment: Please note that this applies to Spring 3 onwards

Answer (score 13):

Since its after a longtime since the correct answers.

Skaffman may be correct in terms of usability of JpaTransactionManager for multiple databases.

But there is working solution for using 2 different databases with 2 different JpaTransactionManager.

```
  @Bean(name = "db2TransactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager2() throws NamingException {
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
    return txManager;
  }

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws Exception {
     JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
    txManager.setNestedTransactionAllowed(true);
    return txManager;
  }
```

`@Primary` should be used to specify for the ones where you don't specify qualifier name in `@Transactional`

Answer (score 6):

You have to specify two transaction managers for that in application-context.xml as below:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="manager1"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="manager2"/>
```

@Transactional attribute will now use its relevant transaction manager.

Comment: This worked for me and I didn't have to specify the qualifier on the txManager beans or in the @Transactional annotation.  I was able to access two different session factories also.

Comment: Ya, same with me. I also didn't have to specify qualifier with @Transactional annotation.

Comment: Interesting, if I look at `AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser` which processes the `tx:annotation-driven` all is done once per context only! So the second line is totally useless.

Comment: This worked for me! It's a pity that Spring official document doesn't mention this trick to set up multiple DataSourceTransactionManager.