# Reference two databases with Connection in java

Tags: java, sql, database, database-connection

I have two local databases I'm trying to connect to using Java's Connection class.  It's easy enough to connect to the first database using:

```
public Connection conn;
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
```

How can I add a second database to that same connection?  They're both on the same server so it should be fairly simple but I can't find the right commands to do it.

Thanks

Comment: why do you want to connect two databases from the same connection? to replicate?

Comment: So that I can run transactions that query both databases

Comment: say if you have table1 in db1 and table2 in db2, so you need to run queries joining table1 and table2?

Comment: More like, I have table1 in db1 with columns id1 and id2, and table2 in db2 with columns id1 and id3, and I want to update id3 in table2 conditional on id2 having certain values in table 1 where t1.id2 = t2.id2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Connection is a session with a specific database. You can't use one Connection to communicate with two different databases; for that, you need two separate Connections.

```
Connection conn1 =  DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString1);
Connection conn2 =  DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString2);
```

Comment: That's the workaround I was using but I was hoping there would be a better way to do it

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
public Connection conn1;
conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString1);
public Connection conn2;
conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString2);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Instance members shouldn't be public.
2. Connection should be a local variable, not an instance member.

You can only connect to one database at a time with a single Connection. Ergo you need *another* Connection.

Comment: Thanks, but I was already following 1 and 2 in my code, I'd just simplified it for the example here.

Comment: @Zain I don't see how that simplifies anything. Actually it just wastes your time and mine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use J2EE, JTA transaction manager to accomplish this.

Comment: Using 2 connections is not very transaction safe. With JTA transaction manager it is possible to achieve this functionality in transparent manner,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961566/how-to-configure-transaction-management-for-working-with-2-different-db-in-sprin

Comment: I would have thought using two connections wasn't transaction-safe at all, but that statement isn't the same thing as 'you have to use'. OP has said nothing about transaction safety across the databases being a requirement, nor about being in a J2EE environment where JTA is even available.

Comment: since it says, 'How can I add a second database to that same connection', using of two connections does not seems to be the option as I think. So what left is to access databases in transaction safe manner that is why i suggested to use JTA, as I am not aware of any other mechanism to achieve this.

Comment: The other mechanism is to rejectb the terms of the question, as everyone else has done.