# Two datasources using the same entities/repositories using spring data jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I need help setting up an application which copyies a subset of data from our in-house  (master) MS SQL database DB1 to another MySQL database DB2 which runs on a webserver to be used by an webapplication (i.e. I want to sync those two databases). The tables have the same name on both databases, although only a subset of the attributes/columns are defined on DB2. I'd like to use (xml-configured) spring, spring data jpa (i.e. the JpaRepository interfaces) and hibernate as jpa-provider, because I want to build up knowledge with these tools.

As far as I could pick up from other discussions, the basic idea is to define spring to use two entityManagerFactory beans using one distinc dataSource each (one for each database) according to:

[spring jpa hibernate with more datasources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113739/spring-jpa-hibernate-with-more-datasources)

I could then inject the persistence-unit-specific EntityManagers and do database-operations using these. But I'd like to use the spring-data repositories: At the moment I have defined a JPA Entity incl. fields for all the tables/attributes I need on DB2. For each Entity, I've set up an @Repository-annotated interface which impements JpaRepository, these repositories are then injected into corresponding Service-classes.

Is there any way to inject these repositories into my servce layer an assign a persistence-unit (i.e. select the database I want to use) to them during injection? I could in principle define all repositories twice, once for each database usign the @PersistenceContext(name="NameOfPersistenceUnit") annotation, but I hoped that this would not be necessary.

Could someone outline how I could achive my goal using the named frameworks, or are there easier ways to copy data between two databases programmatically. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks very similar to issue where you want ability to point to different databases at run time but want to keep only one set of repositories. See if this thread helps.. [Spring Data + JPA with multiple datasources but only one set of Repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612288/spring-data-jpa-with-multiple-datasources-but-only-one-set-of-repositories)