# Two Spring Repositories for same entity - Different Datasources

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, datasource

I have a scenario where I have a Database with some records in it already.
I need to replicate the information in other database , with the datasource information derived in the run time.

The entity model remains the same in both the databases and all I need is to migrate the information from one to another.

Related question I found is this : [Two datasources using the same entities/repositories using spring data jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29911758/two-datasources-using-the-same-entities-repositories-using-spring-data-jpa)

Also in the solution there it is mentioned to use a 'AbstractRoutingDataSource' which can derive the information from the tenant.

My use case does not fit there exactly, or I do not know how to fit it in.

My requirement is like

```
DataSource1 -> EntityManager1 -> Persistence Unit1.
DataSoruce2 -> EntityManager2 -> Persistence Unit2.
```

Both the persistence unit has the same set of classes.

I need to do

```
EntityRepo_associated_with_datasource1.find()  
 and then write them to  EntityRepo_associated_with_datasource2.saveAll().
```

Any pointers on this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to syncronise 2 databases use the [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/2015/07/executing-liquibase.html) API do not try and do this with JPA.

You can create a changeset that blows away all the data in the database to by updated, then fills it with data from the replicated set.

Comment: Can we read based on some conditions and replicate only those selected records ?

Comment: Yes, it's not simple you will have to override some of the liquibase classes, but I have tried both ways and in my opinion liquibase is by far the easiest.

Comment: Is there a actual technical working model for this without using liquibase ?