# Create Java objects from multiple sources - configurable deployments

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, persistence

I have some classes (`Teacher`, `Student`...) and I want to create objects from them with fields backed from more database sources in a configurable way. The information where the data source is for a particular class field can be different depending on deployment (configuration of the App). I want to have the information about database sources persisted as well. (I use Hibernate for persisting.)

Example of deployment 1:

- `Teacher.firstname` should be persisted from LDAP
- `Teacher.lastname` should be persisted from LDAP
- `Teacher.email` should be persisted from PostgreSQL
- `Student.firstname` should be persisted from PostgreSQL
- `Student.lastname` should be persisted from LDAP
- `Student.email` should be persisted from PostgreSQL

So there needs to be also information persisted in some DB that `Teacher.firstname` is backed in LDAP, `Teacher.email` in PostgreSQL etc.

Example of deployment 2:

- `Teacher.firstname` should be persisted from PostgreSQL
- `Teacher.lastname` should be persisted from PostgreSQL
- `Teacher.email` should be persisted from PostgreSQL
- `Student.firstname` should be persisted from PostgreSQL
- `Student.lastname` should be persisted from LDAP
- `Student.email` should be persisted from PostgreSQL

So there needs to be also information persisted in some DB that `Teacher.firstname` is backed in PostgreSQL, `Student.lastname` in LDAP etc.

I use Spring (not only) for DI and JPA (Hibernate) for persistency, but it's not so important. I am not looking for an answer how to configure 2 datasources in Spring/JPA, but rather how to design that problem generally.

Comment: Well there's this http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/reference/ but that doesn't fix the issue of configurable deployments. You question is probably a bit broad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple database with Spring+Hibernate+JPA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902997/multiple-database-with-springhibernatejpa)